# Trouble running the Loop function in excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I got this code but it doesn't seem to run all the way to the end. Gets stuck and debugger just highlights either the Loop keyword or `i = i + 1` row. What am I doing wrong?

I tried `If` statement or `For … Next` but nothing seems to work.

```
Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    Dim i As Integer    
    i = 2

    Do Until i > 586
        Range("B2").Formula = "=sheet2!CS" & i & ""
        Range("B3").Formula = "=sheet2!CR" & i & ""
        Range("B4").Formula = "=sheet2!CQ" & i & ""
        Range("B5").Formula = "=sheet2!CP" & i & ""
        Range("B6").Formula = "=sheet2!CO" & i & ""
        Range("B7").Formula = "=sheet2!CN" & i & ""
        Range("B8").Formula = "=sheet2!CM" & i & ""
        Range("B9").Formula = "=sheet2!CL" & i & ""
        Range("B10").Formula = "=sheet2!CK" & i & ""
        Range("B11").Formula = "=sheet2!CJ" & i & ""
        Range("B12").Formula = "=sheet2!CI" & i & ""
        Range("B13").Formula = "=sheet2!CH" & i & ""
        Range("B14").Formula = "=sheet2!CG" & i & ""

        'Copy and PasteSpecial a Range
        Range("AL18").Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("CV" & i & "").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably won't affect your problem, but you could remove the ` & ""` after all the `i`s, it does nothing useful. And why not use `For i = 2 to 256` ... `Next i`?

Comment: Never seen something like this. The code is working on my computer but it is slow, we can make it 10 or maybe 100 times faster but you have to explain what you are trying to do. As much as I could figure out, you're looping through the rows 2-586 in the columns CG:CS and pasting each  value into each row of the range B2:B14 and you probably have a formula in AL18 that calculates something (maybe sums up the range) from the range B2:B14 whose result you then paste into the actual row of column CV. So you should write something like that in your question which you can edit at any time.

Comment: I'll answer and improve your code, but I need to know the formula in cell 'AL18' and on which sheet it is (I'm guessing Sheet1) and also on which sheet are the cells in the range "B2:B14".(I'm guessing on Sheet1, too). A quick tip: When you write Range("B2").Formula... you are referring to the  ActiveSheet. Every open workbook has one. Also when you're watching Sheet2 it is the Activesheet and when you go into VBE from Sheet2 or from another workbook, the line of code will refer to that particular sheet you last watched. So it would be best you use Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Formula...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like there's any problems with the code when I tested it..

Here's your code albeit made shorter and see if it works.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim colltr As String

    For i = 2 To 586
        For j = 2 To 14
            colltr = Split(Cells(1, 99 - j).Address, "$")(1)
            Range("B" & j).Formula = "=sheet2!" & colltr & i
        Next j
    'Copy and PasteSpecial a Range

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("CV" & i & "").value = Range("AL18").value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd also get rid of that `Copy` at the end and make that just `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("CV" & i).Value = Range("AL18").Value`.

Comment: What is the idea of `Range("CV" & i & "")`? Especially the `""`?

Comment: Vityata, the Range value needs to be in "" e.g. Range("CV23"). In this case the row element is dynamic and is represented by (" & i & "). Not sure why it needs all the spaces but it doesnt seem to work without them. Once you combine the column and row info you get Range("CV" & i & "")

Answer (score 0):

## A Simple Slow Version

```
Sub LoopTrouble()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
    For i = 2 To 586
      For j = 1 To 13
        Sheet1.Cells(j + 1, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 98 - j)
'        Sheet1.Cells(j + 1, "B") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 98 - j)
'        Sheet1.Range("B" & j + 1) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 98 - j)
      Next
      Sheet2.Cells(i, 100) = Sheet1.Cells(18, 38)
    Next
End Sub
```

## A Faster 'Semi' Array Version

```
Sub LoopTroubleFaster()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim vntLT As Variant
  Dim vntPaste As Variant
    vntLT = Sheet2.Range(Cells(2, 85), Cells(586, 97)).Value2
    ReDim vntPaste(1 To 13, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To 585
      For j = 1 To 13
        vntPaste(j, 1) = vntLT(i, j)
      Next
      Sheet1.Range("B2:B14") = vntPaste
      Sheet2.Cells(i + 1, 100) = Sheet1.Cells(18, 38)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks VBasic2008. I have changed some references in my sheet but it doesn't seem to work although doesn't give me any errors either. I will carry on tinkering with it